# Leetcode question: Flatten binary tree into linkedlist

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-tree, recursive-datastructures

I am trying to solve this problem on leetcode: https://leetcode.com/problems/flatten-binary-tree-to-linked-list/ (***Flatten binary tree into linkedlist***)

[image]

This is my code:

```
class Solution{
   
    TreeNode result;

    public void flatten(TreeNode root) {
        TreeNode res = flattenTree(root, null);
        root = res;
    }

    private TreeNode flattenTree(TreeNode node, TreeNode temp) {

        if (node == null) {
            return node;
        }

        if (result == null) {
            result = new TreeNode(node.val);
            temp = result;
        } else {
            TreeNode result1 = new TreeNode(node.val);
            result.right = result1;
            result = result.right;
            result.left = null;
        }
        flattenTree2(node.left, temp);
        flattenTree2(node.right, temp);
        return temp;
    }
}
```

I believe this is the correct solution because after pointing to `res`, `root` contains the tree in correct format for example input data shown in the first screenshot. This, is the screenshot of inspecting the tree after the method executes.

[image]

But, still I am getting incorrect answer. The leetcode compiler says that the root has not changed at all. This is the outcome.

[image]

Not, sure what I need to do to make leetcode accept is as the correct solution.

Comment: It is quite easy to find LeetCode problem solutions online. Just Google for **leetcode 114 solution java**. First result I got was: https://walkccc.me/LeetCode/problems/0114/ I suggest that you compare your solution with theirs.

Comment: I have actually solved it using another approach. I was just wondering why root = res was not updating the root in this particular solution.

Comment: It's reasonable that you included the information from your debugger variable explorer as an image. But, could you, please, include example input, output, and expected as text?  Images of text are [not well received](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) here.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you're updating the `root` variable inside the `flatten` method. In your code, you're updating the `root` parameter, which is a local variable within the `flatten` method, but this change won't affect the original `root` outside the method. To achieve the desired result, you should modify the tree structure directly instead of trying to reassign the `root` parameter.

updated code:

```java
class Solution {
    public void flatten(TreeNode root) {
        flattenTree(root);
    }

    private TreeNode flattenTree(TreeNode node) {
        if (node == null) {
            return null;
        }

        TreeNode rightSubtree = node.right;

        if (node.left != null) {
            node.right = node.left;
            node.left = null;
            TreeNode lastRight = flattenTree(node.right);
            lastRight.right = rightSubtree;
        }

        if (rightSubtree != null) {
            return flattenTree(rightSubtree);
        }

        return node;
    }
}
```

above code will modifies the tree structure in place by recursively flattening the left and right subtrees and updating the `right` pointers accordingly. It doesn't need to return any new nodes or trees, as it directly modifies the input `root`.

Comment: Have you tried submitting your solution in leetcode? It is not giving correct result.

Comment: i don't have an account, tell me where it fails?